# My one minute progress bar in Tkinter gets less and less accurate every time it loops

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

more details: the thing I'm trying to make is a progressbar that is a minute long and once the minute is over, it restarts and loops. the code at the top is for having the process start automatically when a new minute starts. The problem is that the bar syncs up and starts on its own just fine, but after a minute or two it starts getting slow by a couple seconds, the most confusing part is that it's not consistent at all, it gets slower at a different rate every time I run it. Any help would be much appreciated.

here's my code:

```
import time
from tkinter import *
import datetime as dt
from tkinter.ttk import *

now = dt.datetime.now()
sync_now = '%02d:%02d:%02d' % (now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
sync_now_object = dt.datetime.strptime(sync_now, '%H:%M:%S').time()
second_of_day = int(now.hour * 60 * 60 + now.minute * 60 + now.second)
second_of_day = int(second_of_day / 60) * 60 + 60
hour = int(second_of_day / 60 / 60)
minute = int((second_of_day % (60 * 60)) / 60)
second = int(second_of_day % 60)
target_time = dt.time(hour, minute, second)
target_time_str = str(target_time)
print(target_time)
print(sync_now)

def time_to_num(time_str):
 hh, mm , ss = map(int, time_str.split(':'))
 return ss + 60*(mm + 60*hh)

difference_target_now=time_to_num(target_time_str)-time_to_num(sync_now)
print(difference_target_now)
after_difference = difference_target_now*1000
print(after_difference)

# creating Tk window
app = Tk()
app.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)

# setting geometry of tk window
app.geometry("600x100")

# Using title() to display a message in
# the dialogue box of the message in the
# title bar.
app.title("")

progress = Progressbar(app, orient=HORIZONTAL,
                    length=600, mode='determinate')
def my_progress():
   progress['maximum'] = 60
   progress['value'] = 1
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 2
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 3
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 4
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 5
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 6
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 7
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 8
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 9
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 10
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 11
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 12
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 13
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 14
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 15
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 16
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 17
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 18
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 19
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 20
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 21
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 22
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 23
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 24
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 25
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 26
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 27
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 28
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 29
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 30
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 31
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 32
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 33
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 34
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 35
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 36
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 37
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 38
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 39
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 40
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 41
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 42
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 43
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 44
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 45
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 46
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 47
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 48
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 49
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 50
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 51
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 52
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 53
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 54
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 55
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 56
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 57
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 58
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 59
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   progress['value'] = 60
   app.update()
   time.sleep(1)

   app.after(0, my_progress)
progress.pack()

app.after(after_difference, my_progress)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `sleep()` will block `tkinter.mainloop()`, so better use `after()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Two important things:

- `time.sleep(1)` sleeps *at least* one second. It is not an exact timer.
- Updating the progress bar also takes time, which slows the process even more

In your code, there are blocks like this:

```
progress['value'] = 1
app.update()   # this takes time
time.sleep(1)   # more than 1 second
```

Combining 60 of these will definitely take more than a minute.

To get more precision, use the time difference between the start time and the current time and set the progress bar accordingly.

Here is the updated code. It checks the time difference every 1/10 second and updates the progress bar.

```
def my_progress():
   progress['maximum'] = 60
   start = dt.datetime.now()
   while True:
       diff = (dt.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()  # seconds since bar start
       progress['value'] = diff  # can also use int(diff) to jump 1 sec
       app.update()
       time.sleep(0.1)  # 1/10 second
       if (diff > 60):  # end of bar
          start = dt.datetime.now()  # restart progress
```